# Как задать стили выпадающему блоку, чтобы он не смещал контент под ним, а накладывался на него?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, z-index

У меня есть горизонтальное меню.
По нажатию на один из элементов в этом меню - открывается новое выпадающее меню, выполненное как flex-блок.

```
<!-- на этот пункт надо нажать, чтобы открылось меню -->
<div class="menu-block-2" onclick="myFunction()">
Услуги и цены

<!-- это контейнер с большим меню -->
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">Пункты меню</div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">Пункты меню</div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">Пункты меню</div>
</div>

<!-- Это начало контента, который съезжает под меню при раскрытии, но не должен -->
<header class="header-flex">
  <div class="article-header">Услуга <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span></div>
  <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

Но проблема в том, что простым появлением/скрытием выпадающего меню по нажатию на элемент - я просто делаю видимым или невидимым меню.
В результате, когда меню видимо - оно сдвигает весь контент под ним вниз. 
А мне необходимо, чтобы меню "накладывалось сверху" на контент.
Я пытался реализовать эту задумку посредством position:relative/absolute, но увидел, что absolute разрушает флекс-свойства.
Есть ли какое-то другое решение, чтобы не переделывать/костылить flex-меню, но чтобы все работало как нужно без съезжания, а с наложением типа z-index?
Спасибо.

P.S. По просьбе комментирующего - предоставляю полную версию кода:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #595959;
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #167491;
}

.hide {
    display: none; 
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hide:checked + label + div {
    display: flex; 
}


@media (max-width: 444px) {
 .hide, .hide + label ~ div {
    display: none; 
}

.hide:checked + label + div {
    display: block; 
}

.hide + label:before {
    background-color: #2CB1D9;
    color: black;
    content: "\002B";
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
  
.hide:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2212";
}
  
  .dropdown-menu {
    gap: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block {
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  }
  
  .header-flex {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;  
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .article-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.article-header-price {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar-button {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/feedBackButton.png);
    height: 40px;
    width: 187px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #863e39;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover {
    background-color: #1fa6ce;
    background-image: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  max-width: 1240px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3.jpg');
  border: 0px;
/*   border-bottom: 1px solid 167491; */
}

.menu-block:hover {
 background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3-hover.jpg');
}

.menu-block {
 width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*   padding: 10px 0;  */
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-block-3 {
  min-width: 33%;
  flex-basis: 33.5%;
  max-width: 34%;
}

 .menu-block-divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop-li.gif);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menuTop">
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-1"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-1">О сервисе</div>

  </div>
  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-2"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-2" onclick="myFunction()">
      Услуги и цены </div>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block menu-block-3">
    <div class="icon-3"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-33">Контактная информация </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-1" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Техническое обслуживание авто</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Техническое обслуживание авто</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Акции</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-2" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Рулевое управление</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Рулевое управление - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена рулевой рейки</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт гидроусилителя руля (ГУР)</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
        <input class="hide" id="hd-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="hd-3" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Трансмиссия</label>
        <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Трансмиссия- прайс-лист</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сцепления</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Стоимость и ремонт вариатора</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагноситка и ремонт РКПП</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт раздаточной кородки TOD</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-4" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-4" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Двигатель</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Двигатель - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт турбин</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена маслосъемных колпачков</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена головок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена колец</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена двигателя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена масла в двигателе</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена свечей накала</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт компонентов ГРМ</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена цепи ГРМ</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-5" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-5" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Топливная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Топливная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт топливной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт инжекторной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт узлов системы впрыска</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена и диагностика форсунок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена топливного фильтра</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-6" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-6" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Система электрики</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Электрика - прайс лист</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-7" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-7" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Системы охлаждения</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Охлаждение - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена радиатора охлаждения</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена термостата</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-8" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-8" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Тормозная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система - прайс-лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-4">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-9" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-9" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Выхлопная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Выхлопная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт выхлопной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена гофры глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена резинок глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена средней части глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена приемной трубы глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена кольца глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена прокладки катализатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена заднего глушителя</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-5">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-10" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-10" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Подвеска</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Подвеска - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика и ремонт ходовой</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена амортизаторов</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена ступичного подшипника</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена шаровой опоры</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена стоек стабилизатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена рычагов подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сайлентблоков подвески</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<header class="header-flex">
  <div class="article-header">Замена и ремонт головок двигателя <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span></div>
  <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Дорогой автор, можете добавить к вопросу больше кода, что-бы понять что у вас происходит и как именно вам помочь.

Comment: Добавил полную версию кода

Comment: просто добавьте  position: absolute и  z-index: 1 к #dropdown

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но добавление position:absolute - ломает flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
 
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  var menu = document.getElementById("menuTop");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
    x.style.top = menu.offsetHeight + 'px';
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Добавил position: absoolute, и установку top в зависимости от высоты header, надеюсь это то что нужно)
Рабочий пример [Клактц](https://jsfiddle.net/ow2by14x/22/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это именно то, что нужно.
Все заработало, а также на основании вашего кода, я смог сложить нужные величины с другими блоками (хотя не разбираюсь в JS) - и у меня все теперь складывается и правильно отображается на всех разрешениях.
Благодарю!

Comment: Учи js и удачи во всех начинаниях  [Учебник](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

Никак позиционирование не влияет на flex.
Решение:
https://jsfiddle.net/2v1nea7x/33/

```
<!-- на этот пункт надо нажать, чтобы открылось меню -->
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-block-2">Услуги и цены</div>


  <!-- это контейнер с большим меню -->
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">Пункты меню</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">Пункты меню</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">Пункты меню</div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Это начало контента, который съезжает под меню при раскрытии, но не должен -->
<header class="header-flex">
  <div class="article-header">Услуга <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span></div>
  <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-block-2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 44px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
  -moz-border-radius: 24px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: darksalmon;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 24px 0;
  background-color: #f7f8fa;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 24px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.dropdown-menu._active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu-column {
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid darksalmon;
}
```

```
document.querySelector('.menu-block-2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('_active')
})
```